# Solving the cubic-exponential Diophantine equation $x^3+3=2^n$

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

The Diophantine equation $x^3+3=2^n$ has the obvious solutions $(-1,1)$,$(1,2)$ and $(5,7)$. I have been wondering if there are any other, but my attempts have been fruitless (I tried factoring it over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$, but I don't know the basic properties of this field, such as what the ring of integers are, the class number etc.). Any help in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** We can actually split this into two, more general equations, namely the elliptic curves
$$
x^3+3=y^2
\quad \text{and} \quad
x^3+3=2y^2
$$
so this opens up another method for solving it.The first one is, in fact, a special case of the infamous Mordell equation.

**Edit 2:** Looking at this paper by Tzanakis and De Weger :http://www.math.uoc.gr/~tzanakis/Papers/PracticalSolutionThueEq.pdf
I was wondering if we could use the methods explained in Section 3 and extend them to these equations (the methods in the paper, however, require some computational machinery).This could lead to solving a Thue equation, which has only finitely many integral solutions and the general method for solving them is in the paper linked.

Comment: You missed at least another obvious solution: $(-1,1)$. According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2B3%3D%3D2%5En) these are the only possible solutions.

Comment: Oh wow, that's embarrassing :D

Comment: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [Tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: No worries, everything's fine :)

Comment: Another possible approach is to consider $x^3+3=2y^3$ and $x^3+3=4y^3$. This implies that $x/y$ is very close to the cube roots of 2 or 4, so close that only finitely many solutions are possible, by Thue's theorem or just results on continued fractions.

Comment: That is probably the best method, because $x^3-2y^3=3$ is a Thue equation and the solutions of these are linked in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Two cases:

$1)$ $n=2k$. Then $x^3+3=\left(2^k\right)^2$. But $a^3+3=b^2$ has $2$ integral solutions (http://oeis.org/A081119) $(a,b)=(1,\pm 2)$, so $(x,n)=(1,2)$.

$2)$ $n=2k+1$. Then $(2x)^3+24=\left(2^{k+2}\right)^2$. But $a^3+24=b^2$ has $8$ integral solutions (http://oeis.org/A081119, in particular http://oeis.org/A081119/b081119.txt)(I found them with a program, or you can see [these tables](http://hr.userweb.mwn.de/numb/mordell.html))
$$(a,b)=(-2,\pm 4),(1,\pm 5),(10,\pm32),(8158,\pm736844),$$
so $(x,n)=(-1,1),(5,7)$.

Mordell Equations $x^3+k=y^2$ for $k\in\Bbb Z_{\neq 0}$ are fully solved when $|k|<10^4$ (were solved in $1998$; see [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1000281602647)), so we can always use this method when the numbers aren't very large.

Comment: But what are the methods for solving a Mordell equation in general,i.e. what does a computer program do to solve them?

Comment: @BogdanSimeonov The oeis links I gave show the complete amount of integral solutions (they're fully solved since $1998$). Once you know there must be exactly $8$ solutions, you can simply find them with a program by testing e.g. $a\in[-10^6,10^6], b\in[0,10^6]$, or see the [tables](http://hr.userweb.mwn.de/numb/mordell.html) I gave.

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but how are they actually solved is my question, i.e. how have computers solved them for all the k up to 10^4

Comment: @BogdanSimeonov It's the three mathematicians in $1998$ who were able to solve it for $|k|<10^4$ in their paper in the [link I gave](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1000281602647) (using efficient algorithms for programs). See [here](http://www.inf.unideb.hu/~pethoe/cikkek/67_MORDELL.pdf) for some parts of the paper, which might give you an idea how they solved it.

Comment: @BogdanSimeonov One approach is this: consider $x^3+3=2y^2$. Now we add $a^3-2$ to both sides for a suitable integer $a>0$ to get: $(x+a)(x^2-ax+a^2)=2(y^2+b)$, now it is sometimes possible to show that there is a prime factor of the L.H.S. such that $-b$ is a quadratic non-residue. A classic example is $y^2=x^3+7$, where adding 1 to both sides works.

Comment: @Aravind Only applicable if there are no solutions. In this case, there are solutions.

Comment: @BogdanSimeonov If you're unaware, there's [this great paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf) with elementary methods for solving simpler Mordell's equations.

Comment: I asked a similar question (not related to tenth powers) with $a^3+24=b^2$ and is equivalent to the Diophantine equation $a^3+24=b^5$.